# schedule a job for every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the following `job scheduler` code to print `Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!-` every day at 12AM.

```
// executes every day at 12:AM
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, new schedule.Range(1, 6)];
rule.hour = 15;
rule.minute = 14;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
console.log(rule);
    console.log('Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!---------------------------');
});
```

How can I print for every `5` minutes
I used the following way but it is not working...

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

rule.minute = 5;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
console.log(rule);
    console.log('Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!---------------------------');
});
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

rule.minute = new schedule.Range(0, 59, 5);

schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log(rule);
    console.log('Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!---------------------------');
});
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use the [cron format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule):

```
var event = schedule.scheduleJob("*/5 * * * *", function() {
        console.log('This runs every 5 minutes');
    });
```

The cron format consists of:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    |
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and good examples are given on http://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/nodejs-cron-schedule-examples/